# Victory charts - values are not aligned properly

Tags: react-native, graph, react-native-svg, victory-charts, victory-native

I'm using victory chat to display line graphs on the basis of time. Also using Scatter plots to display points.

Since I did not get events when I pressed in lines I ended up using scatter plots.

> In this example, you can see the values are aligned correctly
> x-axis the graph line stopped on Saturday-30. But the actual end
> should be on Sunday-31

Is there any way i can align the data with this implementation
or please suggest an alternate way.

[image]

```
    const points = [24, 24, 23, 23, 22, 20, 21, 21, 21, 20, 22, 19, 19, 20];
const dateList = [
    '2021-10-18',
    '2021-10-19',
    '2021-10-20',
    '2021-10-21',
    '2021-10-22',
    '2021-10-23',
    '2021-10-24',
    '2021-10-25',
    '2021-10-26',
    '2021-10-27',
    '2021-10-28',
    '2021-10-29',
    '2021-10-30',
    '2021-10-31',
];

const DataDots = (props) => {
    const { x, y, datum } = props;

    const dotStat = getGraphPointStats(datum?._y);
    const onPressDots = () => {
        const { _x, _y } = props?.datum;
        setDeviationInfo({ index: _x, value: _y });
    };
    return (
        <TextSVG x={x} y={y} fontSize={30} onPressIn={onPressDots}>
            <Circle cx={x} cy={y} fill={dotStat?.color} r={6} />
        </TextSVG>
    );
};

return (
    <VictoryChart>
        <VictoryLine name="line" interpolation="natural" data={points} />
        <VictoryScatter name="points" data={points} size={2} dataComponent={<DataDots />} />
        <VictoryAxis
            scale="time"
            tickValues={dateList}
            tickFormat={(date) => {
                return `${moment(date).format('ddd')}\n ${moment(date).format('DD')}`;
            }}
        />
    </VictoryChart>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue
data should be formatted like this

```
[{x:new Date(),y:value}]
```